# Core Video pixel buffers as GL_TEXTURE_2D

Tags: macos, opengl, core-video

So I've setup CVPixelBuffer's and tied them to OpenGL FBOs successfully on iOS. But now trying to do the same on OSX has me snagged.

The textures from CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage return as GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE instead of GL_TEXTURE_2D targets.

I've found the kCVOpenGLBufferTarget key, but it seems like it is supposed to be used with CVOpenGLBufferCreate not CVPixelBufferCreate.

Is it even possible to get GL_TEXTURE_2D targeted textures on OSX with CVPixelBufferCreate, and if so how?

FWIW a listing of the CV PBO setup:

```
NSDictionary *bufferAttributes = @{ (__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), (__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey : @(size.width), (__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey : @(size.height), (__bridge NSString *)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey : @{ } };

if (pool)
{
    error = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pool, &renderTarget);
}
else
{
    error = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (NSUInteger)size.width, (NSUInteger)size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)bufferAttributes, &renderTarget);
}

ZAssert(!error, @"Couldn't create pixel buffer");

error = CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, [[NSOpenGLContext context] CGLContextObj], [[NSOpenGLContext format] CGLPixelFormatObj], NULL, &textureCache);
ZAssert(!error, @"Could not create texture cache.");

error = CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, renderTarget, NULL, &renderTexture);
ZAssert(!error, @"Couldn't create a texture from cache.");

GLuint reference = CVOpenGLTextureGetName(renderTexture);
GLenum target = CVOpenGLTextureGetTarget(renderTexture);
```

UPDATE: I've been able to successfully use the resulting GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE textures. However, this will cause a lot of problems with the shaders for compatibility between iOS and OSX. And anyway I'd rather continue to use normalised texture coordinates.

If it isn't possible to get GL_TEXTURE_2D textures directly from a CVPixelBuffer in this manner, would it be possible to create a CVOpenGLBuffer and have a CVPixelBuffer attached to it to pull the pixel data?

Comment: Are you using the core profile?

Comment: Given that I didn't know what that was until you mentioned it... probably not.

Comment: Ok I was not using the 3.2 core profile. Even now that I am, Core Video is still using GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE as a target.

Comment: I should note that #import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h> causes a compiler warning that "gl.h and gl3.h are both included." That suggests CoreVideo is not using the 3.2 core profile to me.

Comment: I think if you are using the core profile than it will use GL_TEXTURE_2D, at least thats what it does on iOS. 3.2 is supposted to be compatibile with es 2.0 which supports rectangle textures in TEXTURE_2D

Comment: Yeah definitely switched to 3.2 core, I had to change lots of things to be compatible with it. Perhaps there is a flag I'm missing in my CV setup? I know I can make a GL_TEXTURE_2D target default when using CVOpenGLBuffers but that is no use as I'm after the pixel data.

Comment: BTW iOS doesn't support ES1.0 as a context for Core Video, nor does ES1.0 have rectangular texture support at all. ES2.0 and GL_TEXTURE_2D is the only option (other than GL_RENDERBUFFER of course). The more I research the more I find it undocumented and more likely Core Video on OSX was built before NPOT/rectangular GL_TEXTURE_2D's became the norm, and it likely hasn't been updated. I only see references to people assuming the same thing; nothing to the contrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just came across this, and I'm going to answer it even though it's old, in case others encounter it.

iOS uses OpenGL ES (originally 2.0, then 3.0). OS X uses regular old (non-ES) OpenGL, with a choice of Core profile (3.0+ only) or Compatibility profile (up to 3.2).

The difference here is that OpenGL (non-ES) was designed a long time ago, when there were many restrictions on texture sizes. As cards lifted those restrictions, extensions were added, including GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE. Now it's no big deal for any GPU to support any size texture, but for API compatibility reasons they can't really fix OpenGL.  Since OpenGL ES is technically a parallel, but separate, API, which was designed much more recently, they were able to correct the problem from the beginning (i.e. they never had to worry about breaking old stuff).  So for OpenGL ES they never defined a GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, they just defined that GL_TEXTURE_2D has no size restrictions.

Short answer - OS X uses Desktop OpenGL, which for legacy compatibility reasons still treats rectangle textures separately, while iOS uses OpenGL ES, which places no size restrictions on GL_TEXTURE_2D, and so never offered a GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE at all. Thus, on OS X, CoreVideo produces GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE objects, because GL_TEXTURE_2D would waste a lot of memory, while on iOS, it produces GL_TEXTURE_2D objects because GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE doesn't exist, nor is it necessary.

It's an unfortunate incompatibility between OpenGL and OpenGL ES, but it is what it is and there's nothing to be done but code around it. Or, now, you can (and probably should consider) moving on to Metal.

Comment: Core Video hardware texture were backed by IOSurface, which seems only maps to GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB too, according to the doc of CGLTexImageIOSurface2D.

Answer (score 1):

As this appears to have been left dangling and is something I recently dealt with: no, `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE` appears to be the only use case. To get to a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` you're going to have to render to texture.

Comment: Meta comment: I've marked this as community wiki from the off as all of this was stated or implied in the comments three years ago but it'd be nice to formalise it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, As of 2023, the modern `CGLTexImageIOSurface2D`  is *much* faster than `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` for getting CVPixelData into an OpenGL texture. Just ensure your CVPixelbuffers are IOSurface backed by including `(id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey: @{},` in the attributes to `[[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes]`

You will still be getting a GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, but you'll be getting it way faster. I made a little shader so that I can render the GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE into a GL_TEXTURE_2D bound to a frame buffer.